# TCP connection to remote server

Tags: javascript, tcp, port

I am pretty new to TCP and server connection related issues. I was tasked with implementing a function to check if the port of users connected to our servers is open or closed, to determine when to show them a message on the frontend, informing them of the status of the ports.

After so much research I still can't figure how to make this connection, the function is required to run on the frontend and such makes it even harder. I have tried implementing this same function on the backend and I was able to achieve what I wanted with this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/portscanner). But since this package is dependent on the `net` package of NodeJs, I cant make use of it on the client-side.

I went ahead to implement some custom functions with WebSockets, and even Images, but instead of getting the status of the connection, the browser always gives me a `net:: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error.

Below are some of the codes I have written so far to try and figure out what the problem could be.
I would really appreciate being pointed in the right direction. Thank you

```
export const checkSocketIoConnect = (url, timeout) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let errAlready = false;
        timeout = timeout || 50000;
        let socket = io(url, {
            transport: ['websocket'],
            reconnection: true, timeout: timeout, reconnectionDelay: 1000,
            reconnectionAttempts: 50,
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        });

        // success
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connecting succesfulyy');
            clearTimeout(timer);
            resolve();
            socket.close();
        });

        // set our own timeout in case the socket ends some other way than what we are listening for
        let timer = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('timer');
            timer = null;
            error('local timeout');
        }, timeout);

        // common error handler
        const error = (data) => {
            console.log('errrror');
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
            if (!errAlready) {
                errAlready = true;
                reject(data);
                socket.disconnect();
            }
        };

        // errors
        socket.on('connect_error', error);
        socket.on('connect_timeout', error);
        socket.on('error', error);
        socket.on('disconnect', error);

    });
};
```

```
export const newPortChecker = (url) => {
    let websocket = new WebSocket(url);
    // websocket.send('pinging server');
    websocket.onopen = function(event) {
        setInterval(() => {
            websocket.send('ping');
        }, 30000);
        console.log(event);
    };

    websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    };

    websocket.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    };

    websocket.onclose = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    };
};
```

```
export const portChecker = (cb, host, port, timeout) => {
    let timeouts = (timeout == null) ? 100 : timeout;
    let img = new Image();

    img.onerror = function() {
        if (!img) return;
        img = undefined;
        console.log('open');
        cb('open');
    };

    img.onload = img.onerror;
    img.src = 'https://' + host + ':' + port;

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!img) return;
        img = undefined;
        console.log('closed');
        cb('closed');
    }, timeouts);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem, making use of this package I found. The package makes use of Images in the DOM. Here it is, for anyone looking to solving this problem later in the future. https://github.com/ItsAsbreuk/itsa-browser-portscan